# word meaning "first two"

Tags: single-word-requests

I think there is a word meaning exactly "first two", but I just cant remember the word.

Comment: I am seeking for a single word whose semantic meaning is exactly "first two", and I do understand what "first two"'s semantic meaning is.

Comment: Horse betting has the *exacta*.